# how to change navigation bar background slowly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my navbar background color to change slowly from transparent to white as I hover it. 
I'm using this script to hide the navbar as I scroll down and pop up as I scroll up and it works perfectly. manage to change the color on hover but without transition ...

can someone please help me to add transition?
please see 
www.maimoncpa.com

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code, involving `nav`

```css
nav{
-webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
}
nav:hover {
  background: white;
}
```